# UIAccessibilityFocus protocol not working

Tags: ios8, accessibility, ios8.1, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I want to know when a user shifts the focus away from an accessibility element. I have tried overriding the `accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus()` and `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused()` methods but the methods doesn't seem to be called upon when I navigate to other elements in VoiceOver accessibility mode. I have no idea what is wrong. Is there anything else that I should do to activate these methods?

```
override func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() {
    println("become focused")
}

override func accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus() {
    println("lose focus")
}
```

The current development is on iOS 8.1, using Swift.

Comment: What kind of elements are you trying to track in this way (buttons, custom views, etc.)?

Comment: Any kind of element actually. All elements that can be navigated to, from navigation bar to buttons. Is there something else missing that I'm supposed to implement? I tried it out in VoiceOver mode but these methods don't seem to be called when I swipe to land on another element (nav bar button, button).

Comment: @CherieCH. Are you sure that you've overridden these methods on an accessibility element? Do you see it highlighted by the VoiceOver cursor?

Comment: Hi Justin, what do you mean by highlighted? Currently, the elements are "boxed" in VoiceOver mode (the default look when VoiceOver is activated). I don't see the print lines though if that is what you're asking. So I don't think these methods have been overridden, but I don't know why :/

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
  isAccessibilityElement = true
```

The default value for this property is false unless the receiver is a standard UIKit control, in which case the value is true.

Assistive applications can get information only about objects that are represented by accessibility elements. Therefore, if you implement a custom control or view that should be accessible to users with disabilities, set this property to true. The only exception to this practice is a view that merely serves as a container for other items that should be accessible. Such a view should implement the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol and set this property to false.

Answer (score 0):

More than 2 years after the initial question but I hope this will help anyway.

The problem occurs because you may have overriden these methods in your view controller, you should **implement your code in your accessibility element directly**.

You could create a class to define the accessibility element or just make an extension of its superclass where you put the `UIAccessibilityFocus` overriden functions.